# Generic next() and previous() method for CaseItearble

Tags: swift

Suppose we have an enum and want to enumerate over it :).
If it has Int rawValue we can be provided with next and previous items using computed vars like this.

```
enum Fidelity: Int, CaseIterable { 
    case pixel
    case point
    case average
    case datapoint

    var previousFidelity: Fidelity {
        return Fidelity(rawValue: rawValue - 1) ?? .pixel
    }
    var nextFidelity: Fidelity {
        return Fidelity(rawValue: rawValue + 1) ?? .datapoint
    }
}
```

I went further and created and extension for CaseIterable which allows next() and previous() for a wide range of types.

```
// Let's test Swift 4.2 for enumerating enum
// Too complex, not very efficient, but interesting
extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable  { 
    func next() -> Self? {
        let all = Self.allCases
        let idx = all.index(of: self)!
        let next = all.index(after: idx)
        return (next == all.endIndex) ? nil : all[next]
    }
    func previous() -> Self? {
        let all_reversed = Self.allCases.reversed()
        let idx = all_reversed.index(of: self)!
        let next = all_reversed.index(after: idx)
        return (next == all_reversed.endIndex) ? nil : all_reversed[next]
    }
}
```

The question is how efficient or inefficient my solutions are (i.e. speed, memory)?
Are there any ideas for doing the same or similar things, perhaps `offset(by: )`.

Comment: Maybe [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swift) would be more appropriate for this question

Comment: Every day brings some discoveries (for me),  @ielyamani. Yes, Code Review looks like a better place for such a question. Yet, I'd like to leave it here in hope someone helps me with the `offset(by: )` part.

Comment: Your first implementation is more efficient because it uses the raw value instead of an array lookup. You can do that generally for enums with are RawRepresentable with an “integral” raw value type. That would apply to `enum Fidelity: Int` but not to a `enum Foo: String`. – But did you check if performance is really an issue here? For enums with four cases the array lookup should be negligible.

Comment: @Bhaumik: Re your edit suggestion: This question is about the Swift language and unrelated to the iOS operating system.

Comment: No need to reverse your collection, you can use `index(before:)` all you need is to constrain `AllCases` to `BidirectionalCollection`. `extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable, AllCases: BidirectionalCollection {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `previous()` using `offsetBy` this way:

```
func previous() -> Self? {
    let all = Self.allCases
    var idx = all.index(of: self)!

    if idx == all.startIndex {
        return nil
    } else {
        all.formIndex(&idx, offsetBy: -1)
        return all[idx]
    }
}
```

---

You can combine both `next()` and `previous()` in a more generic offset function:

```
extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable  {
    func advanced(by n: Int) -> Self? {
        let all = Self.allCases
        let idx = all.index(of: self)!
        //An enum with a raw type has at least one case
        let lastIndex = all.index(all.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)
        let limit = n > 0 ? lastIndex : all.startIndex
        if let newIndex = all.index(idx, offsetBy: n, limitedBy: limit) {
            return all[newIndex]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like so

```
let average = Fidelity.average  //average
average.advanced(by: 1)         //datapoint
average.advanced(by: 2)         //nil
average.advanced(by: -3)        //pixel
```

Comment: you can use `func index(before i: Self.AllCases.Index) -> Self.AllCases.Index`. You just need to constrain `AllCases` to `BidirectionalCollection`. `extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable, AllCases: BidirectionalCollection {`

Comment: I like the idea of restricting AllCases to BidirectionalCollection and thus obtaining `index(before: )`, @Leo. Feels Swifty.